# sorting strings in an array by including a certain character with lambda -- using contains?

Tags: java, lambda, contains

I'm working on creating a method that sorts strings in an array, by putting all words that contain "e" up front (in their original order relative to each other). I'm having trouble determining a way to do this. It doesn't seem to allow ".contains()", and I don't understand why this is. I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me.

Here's my code, in which my IDE tells me the use of "contains" is unresolved.

```
   /**
     * Sorts an array of Strings so that words that contain the letter 'e'
     * appear before all the other words.
     *
     * @param words the array of strings to be sorted.
     * @return a sorted array of Strings.
     */
    public String[] sortByLetterE(String[] words) {

       //create new String[]
       String [] eFirst = new String[words.length]; 
       
       //collect strings that include E/e
       eFirst.add(words.forEach(word -> {
           word.contains('E') || word.contains('e'); 
       }));

       //collect the remainders
       eFirst.add(words.forEach(word -> {
           !word.contains('E') && !word.contains('e'); 
       }));

       //return sorted array
       return eFirst; 
    }
```

I'm also not totally clear on how to sort an array in such a manner. All I'm finding in my "sorting" searches is people giving the obvious .compareTo to sort things alphabetically/numerically, which doesnt help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `Arrays.sort()` with a custom comparator. `Arrays.sort()` is stable and as a result, it will preserve the order of equal elements. Here's example code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] words = {"cat", "eel", "dog", "elephant"};
        Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> (a.contains("E") || a.contains("e") ? 0 : 1)));
        for(String word : words)
            System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
eel
elephant
cat
dog
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for your help! that clears up how to create comparators.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Not certain that sorting is the proper way to go here.  For long lists it could be overkill (of course, so could this).

The following groups the words based on containing an 'e' or not.  The words are mapped as they are encountered so their relative order remains the same.  The two lists are then concatenated to each other for the final result.

```
String[] sorted = Arrays.stream(words)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                w -> w.toLowerCase().contains("e") ? 0 : 1))
        .values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .toArray(String[]::new);

for (String s: sorted) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Prints

```
eel
elephant
cat
dog
```